# Why is impPixel = row[8] out of range and is nesting if statements okay in python?

Tags: python, excel

I am beginner to python but have two questions

I am writing a script to search through an excel file and read how many good https requests I receive. All my functions seem to work until it's time to access the excel file.
One of error I see is :

```
['urlRequest.py']
('What is:', ['import csv'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urlRequest.py", line 100, in <module>
    impPixel = row[8]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know trying to access a list won't happen if I tried to access for example:

```
list['cookies','baker','kitchen]
# accessing list[0],list[1], list[2] , 
# will return an element but list[3] will throw an out of range error.
```

Also, I printed row before my loop and I don't understand the error it gives:

```
['import csv']
```

I looked at my excel file and it doesn't seem to be out of range. Any help would be appreciated.

Thirdly -----> I am not sure if I am using my nested if statements correctly.

Here is the current state of my code:

```
import sys
import csv
import requests

from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError





##########################################################################################


# Initial count value for URLs:
goodURLs = 0
badURLs = 0
nullURLs = 0


# with open("SolutionsData.xls", "r") as f:
#     reader = csv.reader(f)
#     next(reader)

# Remember to open() to read the file Michael
# should be xls extention or .cvs ?



##########################################################################################

# startswith() looks for an return a string

def getURLs(str, impression, st):
     if ('Unreachable' in str or str.startswith('4') or str.startswith('5')):
         print "For tacticID: " + impression
         print "URL: " + st
         print "current state : " + str


##########################################################################################




# This function will look for URl request and update then as needed
# onlt check the colums needed  
def countingFunc(str):
    if (str.startswith('2') or str.startswith('3')):
        global goodURLs
        goodURLs += 1
        stringCount = str(goodURLs)
        return stringCount
    elif (str.startswith('4') or str.startswith('5')):
        global badURLs
        badURLs += 1
        stringCount = str(badURLs)
        return stringCount



  ##########################################################################################

# URL request & update the count values. 
def apiCollector(st, impression):

    # regular expression to be tested  
    st = st.translate(None, '[]\'\"\\')
    try: 
        r = requests.head(st)
        code = r.status_code
        str = str(code)
        stringCount = countingFunc(str)
    except:
        str = 'Unreachable'
        global nullURLs
        nullURLs += 1
        stringCount = str(nullURLs)
    str = getURLs(str, impression, st)
    #print str
    return str  



##########################################################################################


# This is the main logic in the file, it will 
# Open the given excel spreadsheet
# The CSV file is opened and read.Checks impression pixel URLS 
# Run the given functions then deliver an ouput 
# I can use csv.DictReader() instead but lets strive for performance

excelData = sys.argv[0]
print(sys.argv)
with open(excelData) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        impPixel = row[8]
        tacticID = row[1]
        if "http" in impPixel:
            if "," in impPixel:
                splitter = impPixel.split(',')
                for item in splitter:
                    api = apiCollector(item, tacticID)
                else:
                    api = apiCollector(impPixel, tacticID)  
    print "Successful URL requests: " + str(goodURLs)
    print "Failed URL request: " + str(badURLs)
    print "# of unreachable URL: " + str(nullURLs)
```

Comment: print(row).  You will see row[8] doesn't exist.

Comment: @user2263572 I printed row and got ['import csv'], I'm confused on why it is printed that, any idea or suggestions?